# WP_Query on custom key and value

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I have a posts with a `Ymd` date custom field. I would like the posts to be able to:

- Displays the posts where the date is not expired (lower than current date)
- Displays the posts that have the same [Week Number](http://week-number.net/programming/week-number-in-php.html) as current day week number

I have achieved the first point by doing a `meta_query` with the date custom field but I can't find any way to achieve the second point with the same custom field because it's a date rather than a week number.

---

This is my current code, or how I wanted it to be:

```php
$args['meta_query'] = array(
  'relation' => 'AND',
  array(
    'key' => 'date_held',
    'value' => date('Ymd'),
    'compare' => '>',
  ),
  array(
    'key' => date('W', 'date_held'),
    'value' => date('W'),
    'compare' => '=',
  ),
);
```

---

Is there any way I could achieve this without adding another custom field by modifying the current custom field date into week number then compare it within the `WP_Query` argument?

Edit: Fixed the code to be like what I wanted

Comment: Create another datefield like `$today` but use something like $dayofweek,  set it to php date() function with a parameter of `w` for day of week.  Now add a 2nd meta query with or comparison and use $dayofweek with compare value of `=`.

Comment: @rudtek - what do I use for the `key` field? I tried the `date_held` and nothing changes

Comment: @AftarFadilah do you mean week number or day of the week? And... Do you want to show posts with the same week number from next years?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż - I want to show posts with the same week number as today's week number.

Comment: @AftarFadilah no matter which year are they in? For example if current week number is 15, then should post from 15th week of 2025 year be showed?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż - If it's possible, current year will also be helpful

Comment: looks like this worked!

Comment: @rudtek - It doesn't. I can't modify the `key` before comparing it to the `value`. I think the method is not officially available yet and require custom SQL queries.